# Lighttpd: Redirect specific location and sub-locations from HTTP to HTTPS (without using domain name)

Tags: web-server, http, redirect, https, lighttpd

#### I would like to redirect a specific section of a website from HTTP:// to HTTPS:// using Lighttpd.

I've been looking at this 
[Lighttpd wiki entry](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/HowToRedirectHttpToHttps), but the examples don't work the way I want.

I have two requirements:

1. **No specific domain should be specified in the URL redirection configuration.**

   - *NOT* something like this: `"^/(.*)" => "https://www.example.com/secure/"`
2. **The redirection should also be applied to sub-items of the location, i.e.**

   - *http://* hostname/secure => *https://* hostname/secure
   - *http://* hostname/secure/subdir/file.ext => *https://* hostname/secure/file.ext
   - ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, one of their examples is a near-perfect match to your requirements - just needs tweaked to only work in the secure directory:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/secure/" {
  $HTTP["host"] =~ "(.*)" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://%1/$1" )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, that seems to work perfectly. Of course I needed to wrap around it `$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" { ... }`.

Comment: Great, it was exactly what I was looking for.